# Google Forum short URL not working in Android app Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, google-forms

I am using Google forum in website to fill detail, using that website in Webview of android app. When i try to open the Google forum short link in Webview is showing error : **net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME,  error code :  -10.**

And in webview Screen it show this line :
`intent://<a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/##########/viewform%3Fusp%3Dsend_form;end">forms.gle/************#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;action=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.VIEW_DYNAMIC_LINK;scheme=https;S.browser_fallback_url=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/########/viewform%3Fusp%3Dsend_form;end</a>; could not be loaded because:<br><br>net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Full Url is working fine, Url in browser is working fine.

Language Used : Kotlin,
Android device: Samsung A 10, 
Android version: 9 (pie)

Code used:
`webview.loadUrl("https://forms.gle/#########")`

and used these setting:

````
webview?.getSettings()?.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
webview?.getSettings()?.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
webview?.getSettings()?.setAppCachePath(this.cacheDir.path)
webview?.getSettings()?.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix these type of Issues , we have to ovveride **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method of the WebView Client that we set to Webview. Sometimes the overriding urls can start with **intent**, so they have to be handled in other way. Attached the sample Code below.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                    try {
                        Context context = webView.getContext();
                        Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                        if (intent != null) {
                            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                            ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent,
                                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                            // This IF statement can be omitted if you are not strict about 
                            // opening the Google form url in WebView & can be opened in an 
                            // External Browser 
                            if ((intent != null) && ((intent.getScheme().equals("https"))
                                    || (intent.getScheme().equals("http")))) {
                                String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra(
                                        "browser_fallback_url");
                                webView.loadUrl(fallbackUrl);
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (info != null) {
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                // Call external broswer
                                String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra(
                                        "browser_fallback_url");
                                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                        Uri.parse(fallbackUrl));
                                context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                            }
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    webView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, please explain Your solution as looks complex. I took only few method which i found relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in kotlin by Google support https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12941044?hl=en

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {

                if (url.startsWith("intent://")){
                    val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
                    if(intent != null){
                        val fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url")
                        return if (fallbackUrl != null){
                            mDiscourse?.loadUrl(fallbackUrl)
                            true
                        } else {
                            false
                        }
                    }
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
            }
```